# UIButton setImage not Setting Image, button is Custom

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In my code, I call a function to change the image of my custom UIButton from a blue button to a different colored one.

```
    func changeButtonColor(_ colorChange: String, buttonToChange: UIButton) {
    switch colorChange {
        case "Blue": buttonToChange.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue-glossy-button-blank-hi"), for: .normal)
            print("Blue")
        case "Green": buttonToChange.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "asia2Greenadd"), for: .normal)
            print("green")
        case "Red": buttonToChange.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "asia2Redadd"), for: .normal)
        case "Purple": buttonToChange.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "asia2add"), for: .normal)
    default: print("Error")
    }
    print("hello")
    greenButton1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "asia2add"), for: .normal)
}
```

This function is in the View Controller that it wishes to modify.
Strangely, the `"Blue"` and the `"Green"` get printed when they should.  And after it prints `"Hello"` I tried to set the button image again with its corresponding outlet, but when it returns to my view controller,all the buttons are the same images as before.  Do I have to do this image setting in `viewDidLoad`? Am I missing a step for my view to be modified?

This is where I call `changeButtonColor`

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Back" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ViewController {
            destinationVC.tagColorPairings[button!] = colorToSendBack
            delegate?.changeButtonColor(colorToSendBack, buttonToChange: (button)!)
        }
    }
}
```

RESOLVED
-I was having a button segue back to my root view controller which was pushing an un-updated VC onto the stack, when I really needed to use `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController`

Comment: where do you call `changeButtonColor`?

Comment: Edited OP to include where I called it.  It is part of a protocol that my `ViewController` conforms to

Comment: Show us buttons initialising code

Comment: Issues been resolved.  Thanks for your guys' time!